# JQuery Isotope sort after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-isotope

I tried this

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var $newIems = $("<div class='post-body post item'>itemName</div>")
    $(".items").isotope("append", $newIems, true);
});

$("#sort").click(function(){
    $('.items').isotope({
        getSortData : {
            content: function ( $elem ) {
                return $elem.find('.post-content').text();
            }
        }
    });
    $('.items').isotope({ sortBy : 'date' });
    $('.items').isotope( 'reLayout' )

});
```

But the items wont get sorted. is it possible in general to add new items to the isotope container and sort them after? What I want to do is just to append the new items on the top of my straightDown isotope list.

**Update1:**
The item is already appending on the top with using prepend().
My prepend code is equal to Hady ones (the answer second answer below this question).
But it still appends in the second item because there wont be set a css top value, here is the DOM:

```
<div class="items isotope" style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; height: 354px;">
       <div class="item isotope-item" style="position: absolute;">addedItem</div>
       <div class="item isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;">item1</div>
       <div class="item isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 81px;">item2</div>
       <div class="item isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 172px;">item3</div>
</div>
```

and as you can see, the existing items also didnt get additional +top pixel. So I guess I have to call reLayout() after appending the new item?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `addItems` method. Check the [documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/methods.html) out. There's also a [demo](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/adding-items.html) you can try.

Comment: well I guess u didnt understand the question. the item appends but on the bottom, I want it on the top. so my question was is there a possibility to call sort after appending or something like that, because it doesnt work with the given code

Comment: Well on that link I posted above to the demo there's an example of using "prepend" - that should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

If all that you are after is to insert new items at the start of your container, then you need to **prepend** your newly created items instead of **appending**.

```
$("#add").click(function(){
    var $newIems = $("<div class='post-body post item'>itemName</div>")
    $(".items").prepend($newIems).isotope('reloadItems');    
    return false;
});
```

Comment: It appends at the start of the container, but it gets no css top value, which means it appends directly behind the second one. should I call after reloadItems, reLayout aswell? edit: there is no insert animation and the existing items dont move down aswell

Comment: is it possible that you share your current code and HTML structure on jsFiddle or update your question?